# In iOS UIWebView how to get html DOM content before it finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I am getting an url and I'd like to present it in my UIWebView like this:

```
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

But due to network restriction in China, we cannot access Google services but the page with this url is using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I have to wait for a long time for it to expire since it is not able to get that js file from `ajax.googleapis.com`, what I'd like to do is exchange this script source with local js file in order to enable javascript calls in the future.

I think if I can get the DOM before it finished loading, then I can add my script source to it like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

But how can I do that?

I tried to load my local html file but the params are dynamic from server side.

I tried to call `[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:url]` in all the UIWebView delegate methods but didn't work.

Comment: Anyone please can help comment on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution/workaround is:

Set a timer after sending an url so timer would wait to try to detect the received DOM to check if the `<head>` has been well received once a while.

During the timer running, the received DOM content may not be INTACT until the DOM receiving finishes loading.

But that's ok, since what I want to do is inject some js code into the `<head>` which is the very first part of the DOM content.

So after I successfully injected the `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` into the `<head>` in the DOM, I won't care about when the whole thing finishes loading, if I clicked any button on the page, it would use the jquery code I just injected in the `<head>` instead of the default one.

Anyone has better idea, please do let me know, thanks.